# Springboot devtools trigger file with debug mode

Tags: spring-boot

I am using the devtools starter with the  trigger file activated. To improve the experience, I start the project in debug mode and update the file only when I need to change something that needs the reload of the container.

When the context restarts my changes in methods stopping to work. My guess is: the debug mode is attached with the first classloader loaded by springboot, when springboot destroys it the application classloader and reload, something bad happens. Any guess?